# How to get sql data from two tables and print to one?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm new to PHP and SQL. I'm still learning.
So, I have in my DB 3 tables called **ps_plr**, **ps_plr_ids_name** and **ps_plr_victms**.

- **ps_plr**, I need column: ***rank***
- **ps_plr_ids_name**, I need column: ***name***
- **ps_plr_victms**, I need 2 columns: ***kills*** and ***deaths***

in all of these tables, I have the **plrid** column that will serve as a base.

I need to output an html table having:
*Rank, Name, Kills and Deaths*.

I tried the following code that can print the rank and the **plrid**, but I don't really need the **plrid** on the table, as I said, just as a base to find what I need on the other tables.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "psychostats3_1";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT ps_plr.rank, ps_plr.plrid FROM ps_plr;";
$query .= "SELECT ps_plr_ids_name.name FROM ps_plr_ids_name plrnk, ps_plr plrst;";
$query .= "WHERE plrid=name";


//select task.id, task.name, proj.id, proj.name
//from tasks task, projects proj
//where proj.id=task.project_id; 

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td>");
                printf("<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td></tr>");
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: can you pls show the table strcuture of both the tables?

Comment: join the three table on `pri_id` and use the where clause as `plrid='name' ` id name is string.

Answer (score 0):

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| tutorial_author | tutorial_count |
+-----------------+----------------+
| mahran          |             20 |
| mahnaz          |           NULL |
| Jen             |           NULL |
| Gill            |             20 |
| John Poul       |              1 |
| Sanjay          |              1 |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Let say this is a table `tcount_tbl`
And My another table `tutorials_tbl`

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| tutorial_id | tutorial_title | tutorial_author | submission_date |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|           1 | Learn PHP      | John Poul       | 2007-05-24      |
|           2 | Learn MySQL    | Abdul S         | 2007-05-24      |
|           3 | JAVA Tutorial  | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Now executing the query.

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count
    -> FROM tutorials_tbl a, tcount_tbl b
    -> WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author;
```

This is how I can Join two tables as in your case you haven't mentioned the whole column names So I am just supposing and giving you a brief example for joins. You can do further joins like left join etc to fetch from 3 tables
[Source fetching from 3 tables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Moo0fyzoIHU)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table align="center" border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Kills</th>
<th>Deaths</th>
</tr> 

   $res=mysql_query("SELECT c.* , p.*,d.* FROM ps_plr c,ps_plr_ids_name p,ps_plr_victms d WHERE c.plrid=p.plrid and c.plrid = d.plrid ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
     ?>
        <tr>
        <td><p><?php echo $row[' Rank']; ?></p></td>
        <td><p><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></p></td>
        <td><p><?php echo $row['Kills']; ?></p></td>
        <td><p><?php echo $row['deaths']; ?></p></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Try it Hope this works..